# win32 server certificate validation callback

Tags: c++, ssl, winapi, ssl-certificate

Is there an equivalent of .NET `ServerCertificateValidationCallback` or OpenSSL `SSL_CTX_set_verify` in C++/Win32? I'm trying to intercept a server certificate after it has been validated by either Microsoft CNG or Crypto API, however I cannot seem to find any Win32 callbacks that provide the same functionality (or close to) the .NET or OpenSSL ones.

According to MSDN there is [IBackgroundCopyServerCertificateValidationCallback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bits10_3/nf-bits10_3-ibackgroundcopyservercertificatevalidationcallback-validateservercertificate), however I cannot seem to find any examples of how to set it up.

Note that I'm trying to have a callback that provides any server certificate validated within a process, rather than a specific one for a specific connection.

Comment: certificate validation in what scenario ? if you for instance use `InitializeSecurityContext` (Schannel) - you can set flag `ISC_REQ_MANUAL_CRED_VALIDATION` and after handshake end - call `QueryContextAttributesW` with `SECPKG_ATTR_REMOTE_CERT_CONTEXT` and check cerificat by self

Comment: @RbMm I don't think that's what I'm looking for. I'm trying to receive a notification whenever the CryptoAPI or CNG validate a certificate. Pretty much the equivalent of SSL_CTX_set_verify but in win32 rather than OpenSSL

Comment: As far as I'm concerned， you may find the method:[IBackgroundCopyJobHttpOptions3::SetServerCertificateValidationInterface method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/bits10_3/nf-bits10_3-ibackgroundcopyjobhttpoptions3-setservercertificatevalidationinterface)